# How do we change Community Users' reputation points with Apex?

Tags: apex, community, chatter, reputation

For users in Communities, we want to change their User reputation points with code (Apex). How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did this during a migration from JiveX to Salesforce Community Cloud. You can use the Chatter API (ConnectApi) with Apex to achieve what you're doing. I assume you mean Apex when you say code?

You can use the Chatter API (ConnectApi) [ConnectApi.Reputation class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_connectapi_output_reputation.htm). It has two descriptive properties:

- reputationLevel (a reference to a ConnectApi.ReputationLevel), and
- reputationPoints (a Double that holds the actual number of points the user possesses)

as well as a String property that contains a URL to the reputation.

Additionally, there is a [ReputationPointsRule class](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_reputationpointsrule.htm) that contains information on the out-of-box activites that award points.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Bri's answer (which I recommend), there is an alternative to using the ConnectApi, which is to update the NetworkMember record for a user directly in apex. ReputationPoints is a field that resides on NetworkMember and is updateable.